# How can i run multiple commands in a vagrant trigger

Tags: bash, command, vagrant

I want to run mtuliple commands in a trigger, but it seems to only let me run one. The code below works:

```
  config.trigger.after :up do |trigger|
     trigger.info = "Do something"
     trigger.run = {inline: "echo hi"}
  end
```

None of these replacements for the last line work:

```
     trigger.run = {inline: "echo hi; echo hi again"}
     trigger.run = {inline: "echo hi && echo hi again"}
```

It seems that whatever vagrant is doing to parse these, it uses shellsplit and expects to run everything as one command with multiple parameters, so `;` and `&&` show up in the echo itself.

for example:

```
    trigger.run = {inline: "echo test; test 2 &&"}
```

outputs:

```
    default: echo test; echo test 2 &&
    default: test; echo test 2 &&
```

Comment: You should maybe just use a script here.

Comment: @MattSchuchard that would work but it kills the portability of just being able to deploy a single file to multiple devs :(

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```rb
$script = <<-SCRIPT
echo hi
echo hi again
SCRIPT

config.trigger.after :up do |trigger|
  trigger.info = "Do something"
  trigger.run = {inline: $script}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This one burned so much of my time but I finally figured it out. triggers aren't running bash scripts, they are executing binaries. So you would have to do the following:

```
trigger.run = {inline: "bash -c 'echo test; test 2 &&'"}
```

Source: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/triggers/configuration.html#run

Comment: Good tip! This explained why the files I was writing with the script had an encoding my Linux box couldn't read :-)